# Insert non dynamic content directly after body and into header (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I simply want to insert pure html directly after the body tag.

```
<div class="just-test">Test</div>
```

And also jquery and css into the head section.

```
.just-test { color: #FF000 }

$(".just-test").addClass("another-test);
```

So I found this example, how to add content via wordpress plugin:
[How do wordpress plugins add content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200578/how-do-wordpress-plugins-add-content)

But my question:
How can I insert directly after body and in the head section?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you just add the content to the file? I guess it's `header.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to insert something into the HTML of a WordPress page, you must do this via [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) (and hope that the theme authors call them, but that's a different topic).

There are hooks to insert content into the `<head>` section of a page (e.g. [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)) and into the footer of the `<body>` area ([wp_footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)). But there is no hook which would allow inserting something at the very beginning of the `<body>`.